# Label (or span) not fading out?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I've got a simple label on my page in asp.net, when its generated via HTML it looks like this:

`<span id="LineItemContent_lblLineItemMessage"></span>`

In jquery I do this:

`$('#LineItemContent_lblLineItemMessage').fadeOut(25000, function () {
        });`

Because I want it to eventually fadeOut.  But it never does it simply stays on my page.  Not sure if my syntax is wrong or anything else might not be working right. Can someone shed some light on this?

Comment: Why do you provide an empty callback ? It's optional.

Comment: Note that 25000 is 25 seconds i could be fading out really slow? it actually does http://jsfiddle.net/mB9fe/

Comment: Try to reduce the problem using jsfiddle. Because there it seems to be correct.

Comment: 25000 means you have the timeout of 25secs that means you have to wait for 25secs to see its working....I think you are not waiting for 25sec....

Comment: @ankur20us, 25000 is the interval of animation. Check http://jsfiddle.net/sS3Eb/1/

Comment: yeah i am sorry i used wrong word....

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're executing the script when the DOM is ready:

```
$(function(){
    $('#LineItemContent_lblLineItemMessage').fadeOut(25000);
});
```

---

Also, it is best practice to use the server control's clientid - as it could change in the future:

```
$(function(){
    $('#<%= lblLineItemMessage.ClientID %>').fadeOut(25000);
});
```

Comment: Darn, you beat me to it.

Comment: +1 for the best practices suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're putting the line of jQuery inside document ready tags:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#LineItemContent_lblLineItemMessage').fadeOut(25000, function () { });
});
```